# React : update one value of my state in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to modify a value of my current state with redux.
Here my state :

```
tickets : {
    high_tickets: [
        {
            "value": value,
            "value": value,
            "value": value,
            "value": value,
            "visibility": 1
        },
        {
             ...
        }
    ],
    low_tickets: [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Here my ticket reducer :

```
case 'HIDE_TICKET':
      const i = action.index
      if(action.typeFraud == "high") {
        state = {
          "high_tickets": [
            ...state.high_tickets.slice(0,i),
            {
              ...state.high_tickets[i],
              "visibility": 0
            }
            ...state.high_tickets.slice(i + 1),
          ],
          "low_tickets": [
            ...state.low_tickets
          ]
        }
      }
      else if(action.typeFraud == "low") {
        ...
      }
      return state
      break;
```

I have an error at the line `{...state.high_tickets[i],"visibility": 0}`. Unexpected tocken.

How can I modify only one value of my object and not redifine all values in my reducer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign(state.high_tickets[i], { visibility: 0 })` if you want to mutate the existing object, or `Object.assign({}, state.high_tickets[i], { visibility: 0 })` if you want to create an entirely new object.

It will look like:

```
"high_tickets": [
    ...state.high_tickets.slice(0,i),
    Object.assign(...),
    ...state.high_tickets.slice(i + 1),
]
```